# How Do You Block & Unblock Internet Sites in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, proxypass

How do you block all internet sites and only let some sites through in Apache Proxy?

I want to block all sites except some (e.g. updatemicrosoft.com, .windowsupdate.com , google.it etc.)

I have configure a Forward Proxy Apache (apache2.4.56 version)

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy "*">
Require ip 10.5.166.84 10.5.166.85 10.5.166.86
</Proxy>
```

could you help me on this?

Comment: Please don’t use Apache proxy functionality for anything except to reverse proxy. Yes it works as a forward proxy, but IMHO only because that function  uses the same code that already exists  for reverse proxying. Apache httpd is designed as a web server. A purpose designed “forward” proxy like the venerable Squid should work a lot better and provide much more relevant features.

Comment: IIRC Rather than using  the wildcard `<Proxy "*">` you can restrict proxy access to allow only specific URL’s as proxy targets by specifying the allowed destinations with for example `<Proxy "http://updatemicrosoft.com”> … (access list) … </Proxy>` repeating that as many times as required https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy

Comment: Hi, I have a test with the follow configuration: <Proxy "http://updatemicrosoft.com">
 Require ip 10.5.164.130 10.5.166.84 10.5.166.85 10.5.166.86
 Require all granted
</Proxy> , but Result is NOT OK.

Comment: When I said ***specific URL's*** I meant exactly that ; `Proxy "http://updatemicrosoft.com”` does not cover the HTTPS version `"https://updatemicrosoft.com”` nor any subdomain `*.updatemicrosoft.com` . That is just one of the reasons why people normally don't use Apache HTTPD as forward proxy server. There is, as far as I know, no convenient and robust access control mechanism other than mapping every URL. Be aware that  Windows Update requires additional CDN domain names. See 
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084568

Comment: HI,
Apache in forward proxy mode was a specific request.

I've seen something about <IF> and <Else> iterations, but I can't seem to build a proper one that blocks everything except some sites

Ex:
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'windowsupdate.microsoft.com'">
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/"
    < Else > 
    redirect indexERROR.html
    </ Else >
</If>

Comment: link --> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html